# Ionic - Barcode Scanner returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

In Ionic app, I use [Barcode Scanner](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner) but after scanning it returns: `[object Object]`

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {BarcodeScanner} from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {  
scannedCode="dd";   
  constructor(private barcodeScanner:BarcodeScanner) {}

   scanCode(){
     this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData=>{
         this.scannedCode=barcodeData;
     })
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type is actually an object. You must get the text encoded value in text property:

```
scanCode()
{
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(
      barcodeData => {
        this.scannedCode=barcodeData.text;
      }
    )
}
```

Next time when you get `[object Object]` from some variable, try console loggin it to see ot contents.

```
console.log(barcodeData);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. it is returned as object and you are trying to load in string.

```
export class HomePage {  
  scannedCode:any = {} as any;   
  constructor(private barcodeScanner:BarcodeScanner) {}
  scanCode()
     {
        this.barcodeScanner.scan().then( barcodeData => {
           this.scannedCode=barcodeData;
           console.log(this.scannedCode);
        });
     }
}
```